# Small Vacuum pump driving circuit

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, dc-motor

Please take this **vacuum pump** datasheet for the circuit I am planing to build.
[Vacuum pump datasheet](https://www.schwarzer.com/pdf/SP_PUMPS_DataSheet_ClassECL_Series200L_Type270ECL.pdf)

I like to make a simple motor driver preferably using an SMD type MOSFET.

I am struggling to choose a suitable MOSFET. So far, I have come across with **FDN327N**. Since the pump motor has nominal **250mA** current and the motor won't be running continuously but intermittently, I believe it should do it.

Note that: 5V supply (from Voltage Booster) will be used for both MCU and the motor.

Here is a sample schematic I am willing to follow;
[image]

1. Would that MOSFET do the job?
2. I couldn't be sure  if voltage drop on MOSFET might be an issue for feeding 5V motor with 5V power supply?
3. How can I calculate Rin and Rgs?

Any input greatly appreciated.

Comment: what are the characteristics of the pwm input signal? voltage is the main concern with a MOSFET. As long as you fully turn it on and consider the gate capacitance (imagine it in parallel to Rgs in your schematic) in your pwm frequency you don't really have to be concerned about the voltage drop across its drain-source junction.

Comment: @vicatcu, In fact that, since I didn't have the motor yet, I didn't make my mind in order to decide what sort of input I should use in terms of using PWM and controlling the speed of the motor or just a simple ON/OFF. Therefore, I am not sure about the PWM signal. What do you have in your mind if it would be the case using PWM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would that MOSFET do the job?

At first glance, it's a logic level FET capable of being turned on with 1.8V, and rated at 2A continuous. 250mA is down in the noise on all the graphs. It should work just fine.

> I couldn't be sure if voltage drop on MOSFET might be an issue for feeding 5V motor with 5V power supply?

Rdson is \$<120m\Omega\$ for the conditions of interest. \$V=IR=(0.25A)(0.12\Omega)=30mV\$ No problem.

> How can calculate Rin and Rgs?

A MOSFET gate is high impedance. Rin is for damping oscillations that can occur when the MOSFET gate and trace leading to it create an LC network. Rgs is just a pull down to make sure the MOSFET stays off when the PWM source is undriven (high impedance). A common pair of values that I start with for this circuit is \$100\Omega\$ and \$100k\Omega\$. They'll work for a lot of situations, but there are reasons to change them that are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: thanks a lot. Your clear answer made things obvious for me. I have also almost confirmed my calculations before asking my question. One thing I wasn't sure. You choosed `120 mΩ @ VGS = 1.8 V`. Why wasn't that  `80  mΩ @ VGS = 2.5 V` or the other with 4.5V?

Comment: @Sener You didn't state a PWM voltage, so I used worst case.

Comment: Understood. I am not there yet where I will consider to use PWM or simple switching.